# Pyspark: to_timestamp return incorrect timestamp value

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I just learnt some basic pyspark. I tried to learn how to use to_timestamp to convert a `StringType` to a `TimestampType`
Below is my sample data

```
data = [(1,'10/06/2019 02:00:00 AM')]
schema = ['id','datetime']
df_test = spark_session.createDataFrame(data=data,schema=schema)
df_test = df_test.withColumn('datetime',f.to_timestamp(f.col('datetime'), 'MM/dd/yyyy KK:mm:ss a'))
```

What I thought it will look like

```
+---+-------------------+
| id|           datetime|
+---+-------------------+
|  1|2019-10-06 02:00:00|
+---+-------------------+
```

Instead, the df_test look like this

```
+---+-------------------+
| id|           datetime|
+---+-------------------+
|  1|2019-10-06 03:00:00|
+---+-------------------+
```

Could someone illustrate how this happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd imagine you're in Australia ;) The two times are actually the same(!) because the clocks went forward for one hour at 2AM due to daylight saving.

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

spark.sql("set spark.sql.session.timeZone = AET")

data = [(1,'10/06/2019 01:00:00 AM'), (2,'10/06/2019 01:59:00 AM'),
        (3,'10/06/2019 02:00:00 AM'), (4,'10/06/2019 03:00:00 AM')]
schema = ['id','datetime']
df_test = spark.createDataFrame(data=data,schema=schema)

df_test.withColumn('datetime',f.to_timestamp(f.col('datetime'), 'MM/dd/yyyy KK:mm:ss a')).show()
+---+-------------------+
| id|           datetime|
+---+-------------------+
|  1|2019-10-06 01:00:00|
|  2|2019-10-06 01:59:00|
|  3|2019-10-06 03:00:00|
|  4|2019-10-06 03:00:00|
+---+-------------------+
```